# usort() drops indexes of ingested arrays leading to "Undefined Index" Error

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a multi-dimensional array as such

```
$cars = array(
"names" => array(), 
"prices" => array(), 
);
```

I stuff the array with a loop using data from an external source

```
foreach ($car["listings"] as $car) {
                    array_push($cars["prices"], $car["price"]);
                    array_push($cars["names"], $car["name"]);
                }
```

I want to sort all of the cars in the array `cars` from price low to high.

```
function sortLowtoHigh($key){
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return $b[$key] - $a[$key];
    };
}
```

and the executing function

```
usort($cars, sortLowtoHigh("prices"));
```

I get `Undefined index: prices` as an error even though the array clearly does (confirmed with `print_r()`)

When I add a `print_r()` inside the function, I notice that I only see values and not the array structure I designed.

```
function sortLowtoHigh($key){
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($a);
        echo "</pre>";
        return $b[$key] - $a[$key];
    };
}
```

Simply yields this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Car1
    [1] => Car2
    [2] => Car3
)
```

Can anyone suggest a way for me to achieve the price sorting while keeping the keys intact?

Comment: as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) *"**Note**: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys."*

Comment: You understand that your code won't keep anything in pairs, right? There will be no correlation between the prices and names. You need to actually have a wrapper - `$cars = [0 => ['prices'=>'','names'=>'']]`(short, modern array-assignment). Then you'll have to do `array_push($cars[$c]['names'] , $car['names'])` - so you assign the correct values to the correct sub-array.

Comment: @Memor-X what can I do? This has to be possible with PHP

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie according to the documentation that Memor-X pointed out... usort will remove the keys anyway :(

Comment: @MarkusProctor well you have [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) which will *"Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association"* and you can see this in the first example the page shows

Comment: @Memor-X tried uasort() and still getting undefined index error.

`uasort($cars, cmp("prices"));`

```function cmp($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return $b[$key] - $a[$key];
    };
}```

Comment: @MarkusProctor i think, in your case within the function `$a` is the array of `"names"` and `$b` is the array of `"prices"`. i think you can confirm this by doing `var_dump($a, $b)` before your return

Comment: @Memor-X this is correct. That's what is happening